# jumping cursor when using python interpreter in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, python, cursor

When I am typing in a long command while using the python interpreter in terminal, the cursor will suddenly jump all the way back to the beginning of the line that was just typed and start overwriting.  Shouldn't it wrap?  I am not sure how to fix this.  Is there a Terminal setting?  Is this a bug?  Did I screw up a setting?  I did try to edit by Bash a while ago to get tab completion, but changed it back (I think) when this issue started happening.  I'm not sure I did in correctly.  Still not sure which file to edit for that.  There seems to be several listed in help forums, ~./bashrc,  /bash/profile, etc..

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!
Chuck

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate the same problem by making changes to PS1 in bashrc. Since I don't know exactly what was edited in your case though, try restoring the previous bashrc file using the following.

```
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
source ~/.bashrc
```

EDIT: Close and reopen terminal after running this.

This fixed the cursor overwriting problem in my terminal. Hope this helps you!

Comment: I think that did it!!!  Thanks a ton!  UPDATE:  I guess it didn't work after all.  :(  It seemed to work at first.

Comment: @user2337529 Just to clarify, is this only happening when using the python interpreter or all terminal commands?

Comment: It seems to be only within Python interpreter, but maybe I should try a really long bash command.  I'll post back my results

Comment: @user2337529 Okay.

Comment: @user2337529 Just as a follow up, did you get it to work?

Comment: No, I haven't.  It is only doing it in the Python interpreter, not in Bash.  Sorry, for the delay.  I was out of town for a day.